# One Way One-To-One Association in CakePHP

Tags: database, cakephp

I have an idea of how to do this but it doesn't seem like proper convention. I have a `Submission` model and a `Revision` model each with their similarly named tables. Each `Submission` can have one or more `Revision`s associated to it in a `$hasMany` relationship. The `Revision` model hence has a `$belongsTo` relationship linking back to the `Submission`.

In addition to having this relationship, the `Submission` model needs to have another association (called `activeRevision`) to a particular `Revision` in a `$hasOne` style of relationship. However, the `$hasOne` type requires the foreign key to be in the `Revision` table. I want it to be in the `Submission` table, so I don't need to query all of the `Submission`'s `Revision`s to find the active one. I realized just specifying a `$belongsTo` relationship in the `Submission` would do what I want, but this feels wrong to me as now the two models "belong to eachother".

Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't worry too much because of the 'naming' of the relation. By having the foreign key of the *Revision* inside the *Submission* table, CakePHP *is*, in fact, right that you've created a 'belongsTo' relation.

Although not *strictly* the 'right' (?) relation, in this situation, this looks like it's an easy way to achieve what you want. Just be sure to add an additional condition to your relation to prevent that a revision of *another* submission can be set as the current revision, i.e.;

```
 public $belongsTo = array(
     'Revision' => array(
         'conditions' => array(
             'Revision.submission_id = Submission.id',
         )
      )
 );
```

However, make sure to add a proper comment in your code to prevent confusion if you're (or somebody else is) looking at your code in a later stage. (e.g. "note: using belongsTo relation, because its easier to maintain)

If you *really* want to convert it to a hasOne relation, you'll have to add an additional column to the 'Revisions' table, for example 'is_curreny_revision'. However, you will also need to be sure that *only one* revision of a submission can be set to be the *current* revision.

If you're using PostgreSQL, this can be achieved using a 'partial unique' index (see this question on StackOverflow; [PostgreSQL: Conditional unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938644/postgresql-conditional-unique-constraint)). MySQL does not support partial indexes, so you're out of luck there

Comment: Good enough for me. And thanks for providing that condition tidbit. I was wondering how to go about that.

Comment: Glad I could help, regarding the condition, this does not prevent the wrong record from being *saved* in `revision_id`. You'll have to add a (custom) validation rule in your Model and/or a constraint in the database.