# Most efficient way to enforce business rule on sql data

Tags: sql, triggers, business-logic

So I have a table of Employees that has the fields `EmployeeId` (GUID), `EmployeeNumber` (string), and `IsActive` (bit) among others.  I would like the SQL Server to enforce a rule where any number of records can have the same employee number, but *only* one record of a given employee number may have the `IsActive` bit set at a time.

I'm trying to determine the most efficient or effective way to have the SQL server do this, but so far I've only come up with the idea of using a Trigger.  Considering the trigger, I was thinking I would probably need to use a cursor to iterate each of the rows in the `inserted` table and check each row individually.  And this has me worrying about performance.

I've considered using a constraint, but clearly I can't use a UNIQUE constraint because I'd only be allowed two records.  Is there a better way to handle this rather than a trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The links below explain how to enforce conditional unique constraints based on bit/boolean fields

SQL Server
- [conditional unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/866061/conditional-unique-constraint)

Oracle
- [Conditional unique constraint in oracle db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10317774/conditional-unique-constraint-in-oracle-db)

Postgresql
- [PostgreSQL: Conditional unique constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10938644/postgresql-conditional-unique-constraint)

MySQL
- Doesn't seem to be possible

Comment: I actually went with the filtered unique index as suggested in the SQL server link, but I (despite my best efforts at looking) wouldn't have found that post without your answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A (not too elegant) workaround for this would be to have a numeric field {activity_level} so {EmployeeNumber, activity_level} is unique. Then you should define MAX_INTEGER, or 0, or MIN_INTEGER or whatever value you want as the active-flag (employees with this value are active, all other are not). I know it is not very clean, but it could do the trick if you don't find anything better...